# using `imports` with argument given by lib.mkOption

Tags: nix, nixos

## what i have

using mmm with an hardcoded path in a nixos module works great, here an example:

### nixcloud-reverse-proxy.nix

```
{ config, pkgs, lib, ... } @ args:
{
   config = { ... };
   options = { 
     services.nixcloud-reverse-proxy = {
       configDir = mkOption {
       type = types.path;
       default = ./. + "/reverse-proxy-config-tests/";
       description = ''An absolute path to reverse proxy configurations. This is used for nixcloud.io deployment mainly, where we rebuild the reverse proxy configuration based on many individual configurations.'';
  };  
     };

   imports = 
    let
      # walk through all configs in the mmm and merge them
      mmm = ./. + "/reverse-proxy-config-tests/";
      filesToLoad = attrNames (filterAttrs (k: v: v == "regular") (builtins.readDir mmm));
      configsFromPath = map (el: (mmm + ("/" + el) )) filesToLoad;
    in configsFromPath;
}
```

## question

i would love to replace `mmm` with `config.services.nixcloud-reverse-proxy.configDir` but this leads to:

```
nixos-rebuild build
building Nix...
error: infinite recursion encountered, at /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos/nixpkgs/lib/modules.nix:60:71
(use ‘--show-trace’ to show detailed location information)
building the system configuration...
error: infinite recursion encountered, at /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos/nixpkgs/lib/modules.nix:60:71
(use ‘--show-trace’ to show detailed location information)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as descirbed here: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/30190

i've been thinking about this for quite a while now and paul & me just discovered this solution:

## possible solution 4

we create a `default.nix` inside `reverse-proxy/reverse-proxy-config-tests2` which contains:

```
{  config, pkgs, lib, ... }:
with lib;

{

  # import config files (nixcloud.io specific for reverse proxy configuration)  
  # use the nix module system to have type validation and inherit meaningful default values for options which are not set explicitly
  config = {
  };

  imports =
  let
    cDir = builtins.toPath (./config);

    filesToLoad = attrNames (filterAttrs (k: v: v == "regular") (builtins.readDir cDir));
    configsFromPath = map (el: (cDir + ("/" + el) )) filesToLoad;
    toModule = x: ({ config, pkgs, lib, ... }: {
      options = {};
      config.nixcloud.reverse-proxy.extraMappings = x;
    });
  in
    fold (el: c: c ++ [(toModule (import el))]) [  ] configsFromPath;
}
```

and call it like that:

```
  machine = { pkgs, lib, ... }: {
    nix.nixPath = [ "nixpkgs=${<nixpkgs>}" "nixos-config=/etc/nixos/configuration.nix" ];
    nix.binaryCaches = lib.mkForce [];
    nixcloud.reverse-proxy.enable = true;
    imports = [ ../reverse-proxy/reverse-proxy-config-tests2  ];

    # Needed so that we have all dependencies available for building the
    # container config within the VM.
    virtualisation.pathsInNixDB = let
      emptyClosure = (import <nixpkgs/nixos/lib/eval-config.nix> {
        modules = lib.singleton { boot.isContainer = true; };
      }).config.system.build.toplevel;
    in [ pkgs.stdenv emptyClosure ];
  };
```

## problem

updating the `default.nix` are now stateful as the code updates to `default.nix` need to be copied into the directory with the config(s) we are about to load.

that said, we pick this solution as it does not require a environment variable, let's us change the include path dynamically and just requires another `imports [ ]` in the main `configuration.nix`.

Comment: So, you replaced option assignment with import. If that worked for you, then you may consider another trick like https://github.com/zalora/nixsap/blob/master/modules/default.nix .

Answer (score 3):

In short, no way.

The fact, that you can't define `imports` clause inside `config`:

```
{ config, ... }: {
  options = { ... };
  config = {
    imports = [ ... ];   # <--- error !!!
    ...
  };
}
```

is a note about how NixOS module system works. One of it's assumtions is - you can't branch or otherwise control the number of included modules dynamically based on other config options. That's why many modules define `module.enable` option, which allows that.

So, back to your question, `imports` clause can't depend on `config.services.nixcloud-reverse-proxy.configDir`, because `config` variables requires all `imports` to be already merged. That hardly can be fixed with current module system. Perhaps it's possible to overcome this by using another variable (not `config`), but is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

i finally found a possible workaround:

`builtins.getEnv` can be used to pass a 'varible' in. this is not as good as a `lib.mkOption` but unlike `lib.mkOption` or `{ myPath ? "/reverse-proxy-config-tests/ } : { ... }` it won't create a *infinite recursion* error each time.

this means, before i do: `nix-build -A reverse-proxy` i need to export the environment variable to pass in a path where my custom nix files are at which is similar to --args but is not limited to `nix-build` and should also work with `nixos-rebuild`